# Python print vs bash echo for subprocess PIPE output

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

I tried the two following ways to use subprocess.PIPE to read the live output of another command, but only one of them provides me the output as they are generated, whereas the other one gives me the output after the command terminated. How do I understand it?

## python script used to read from subprocess.PIPE

script.py

```
import subprocess, shlex
from datetime import datetime

command = './loopWithSleep.sh' # or command = './loopWithSleep.py'
print('command used is', shlex.split(command))
# invoke process
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Poll process.stdout to show stdout live
while True:
  output = process.stdout.readline()
  
  if process.poll() is not None:
    break
  if output:
    print(output.strip())
    print(datetime.now())
```

## method 1 (command is a bash script)

loopWithSleep.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 5); do
   echo "iteration" $i
   sleep 1
done
```

When I run the python script script.py, I see it working as expected, there is 1 second delay between each line

```
command used is ['./loopWithSleep.sh']
b'iteration 1'
2021-12-06 11:44:09.764482
b'iteration 2'
2021-12-06 11:44:10.770432
b'iteration 3'
2021-12-06 11:44:11.774778
b'iteration 4'
2021-12-06 11:44:12.782742
b'iteration 5'
2021-12-06 11:44:13.792413
```

## method 2 (command is a python script)

loopWithSleep.py is

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import time

for i in range(1, 6):
    print('Iteration %d'%i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run the python script script.py, I see the process blocked till all the output is available and the subprocess terminated. You can see all the output lines were printed around the same time as shown by the timestamp that I print.

```
command used is ['./loopWithSleep.py']
b'Iteration 1'
2021-12-06 11:46:38.234695
b'Iteration 2'
2021-12-06 11:46:38.234839
b'Iteration 3'
2021-12-06 11:46:38.234877
b'Iteration 4'
2021-12-06 11:46:38.234913
b'Iteration 5'
2021-12-06 11:46:38.234944
```

What is the difference between bash echo and python print such that method 1 prints as soon as the output it available, while method 2 prints all at once?

Answer (score 1):

I later learnt that I actually need to flush the output manually, either using `sys.stdout.flush()` or `print('xxx', flush = True)`. After adding those to the `loopWithSleep.py` script, the script works as expected.

Pardon my ignorance.